# Where can I download the source code for the MySQL database

Tags: mysql, open-source

MySQL is an open source database, where can one download the source?

Comment: Do you want to install `MySQL Server` ?

Comment: if you are using ubuntu `sudo apt-get source mysql-server OR mysql-client OR mysql-common

Comment: Is navigating [mysql.com](http://mysql.com/) an insurmountable obstacle?

Comment: Yes. The source is hard to find, hence the question...

Comment: The source is now on GitHub! https://github.com/mysql (and here's an article about its release to github: http://mysqlrelease.com/2014/09/mysql-on-github/).

Comment: That github account is maintained by a moron and doesn't have all mysql source. Also, even if you download all projects from that account, you can't build most of them because the client source is missing (C connector). I would be understanding... if not for the fact that 2 years have passed.

Comment: how hard is it to answer his question? I'm sure if he is looking for the source there is a psecific reason. Otherwise he would be searching or asking how to install mysql on *buntu!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Click [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) and select Source Code from the drop-down

Comment: the source code is now on GitHub too; see my comment under the question.